# Как выполнить функцию из класса, из которого вызван диалог?

Tags: java, android

Всем доброго времени суток. Помогите пожалуйста! Я создал и вызвал в классе extended_match dialogFragment с 2 кнопками: позитивный и негативный ответ. Но сам dialogFragment находтся в отдельном классе. Вопрос как выполнить функцию getMoney() из extended_match?

Класс confirmDialog:

```
    public class confirmDialog extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Купить прогноз?");
            builder.setMessage("Вы уверенны что хотите купить прогноз? Деньги с вашего аккаунта будут списаны навсегда!");
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.e("Close", "Colse Dialog");
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            Dialog dialog = builder.create();

            return dialog;
        }
    }
```

Клас extended_match (часть):

```
   public void getPredictions(View v){
        confirmDialog dialog = new confirmDialog();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"confirm_buy");
}
   public void getMoney(){

}
```

Comment: Код покажите, пожалуйста

Comment: @Rishka, дополнил

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам необходимо создать интерфейс с двумя методами, которые будут вызываться при нажатии на кнопки Вашего диалога, после чего реализовать его в активити, которая запускает диалог. Затем в Вашем классе `confirmDialog` в методе `onAttach` привести активити к экземпляру вашего интерфейса. После чего можно будет из колбеков кнопок в диалоге вызывать методы интерфейса для дальнейшей обработки нажатий. Более подробно описано в [документации](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents)