# Выполнить действие в Activity после завершения DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment

У меня есть **Activity** в макете которого отображается набор данных. Из этого **Activity** запускаются несколько разных **DialogFragment**, которые вносят изменения в существующий набор данных. После внесения изменений мне нужно их как то обработать, чтобы скорректировать отображение. Так вот, как выполнить какой-либо код после завершения **DialogFragment**?

Comment: Вы же устанавливаете слушатели на нажатия кнопок в диалоге. Вот в них и выполняйте нужные действия.

Comment: @eugeneek, как? Например мне нужно выполнить `.scrollToPosition(position)` для `mRecyclerView`, который находится в **Activity**. Как до него достучаться из **DialogFragment**?

Comment: С [помощью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426080/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3/426083#426083) [колбеков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600600/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-activity-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-dialogfragment?rq=1).

Comment: @eugeneek, спасибо за коммент. Первая ссылка оказалась, именно тем что мне было нужно )